# Stop loading in all Konqueror tabs

Tags: dbus, kde-plasma, konqueror

I have a Konqueror window with multiple open tabs, all are loading due to "Reload All". How can I stop all tabs loading? With `qdbus` I can stop loading the current active tab:

```
qdbus org.kde.konqueror /konqueror/MainWindow_1 org.qtproject.Qt.QWidget.slotStop
```

My idea was to get a list of all open tabs and then stop them one after another using a shell script, but I cannot find a way to list identifiers of all open tabs. An alternative would be to activate the tab next to the current one, stop loading it and repeat. But I could also not find a way to switch to the next tab. Already tried `qdbus org.kde.konqueror /konqueror/MainWindow_1` and `qdbusviewer` for listing all available properties.